# Replacing parentheses with square brackets in mathematical expressions, using backreferences in sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

Is it possible in `sed` backreferencing that we replace the an occurrence or a pattern the same number of times it was referenced?

Example: For a given input,

```
((23 + 5)(23 + 5))
11 x (2+1) = 11 x 3 = 33
3x(5+2)
```

I need to replace all occurrences of `(` with `[` and `)` with `]` using `sed` backreferencing alone (have solved this with `tr` and `sed`).
Also the number of brackets can vary.

Comment: Why use backreferences at all rather than a `g`lobal replace (`s/(/[/g;s/)/]/g`)?

Comment: Please show what you did with tr and sed, and explain why you feel you need to use backreferences.

Comment: I don't think that the question is unclear. It does not show the attempt perviously made or describe _why_ backreferences need to be used. Apart from that, the question is clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you simply want to replace all `(` with `[` and `)` with `]`, then there is no need for backreferences. A simple `tr` will do the job:

```
$ tr '()' '[]' <file
[[23 + 5][23 + 5]]
11 x [2+1] = 11 x 3 = 33
3x[5+2]
```

or, with `sed`,

```
$ sed 'y/()/[]/' <file
[[23 + 5][23 + 5]]
11 x [2+1] = 11 x 3 = 33
3x[5+2]
```

A backreference can only replace something existing in the input with itself, so I'm assuming you're thinking about trying to match the things in-between the parentheses and then to replace them with the same things but in square brackets.  You may do that with a loop:

```
$ sed -E -e ':loop' -e 's/\(([^()]+)\)/[\1]/; tloop' <file
[[23 + 5][23 + 5]]
11 x [2+1] = 11 x 3 = 33
3x[5+2]
```

Here, we first define a label, `loop`, and then do our substitution.  If the substitution did something, then we branch back to the `loop` label.  We need to do it this way because using `s/.../.../g` will not find overlapping matches, and there are overlapping matches as soon as there are nested parentheses.

The substitution `s/\(([^()]+)\)/[\1]/` will find any non-empty string inside parentheses, that does not contain `(` or `)`, and replace that with itself but with the surrounding parentheses replaced by square brackets.

For the input line

```
((23 + 5)(23 + 5))
```

this will cause `sed` to perform the substitution four times:

1. `([23 + 5](23 + 5))`,  the first inner parenthesis is replaced.
2. `([23 + 5][23 + 5])`, then the second inner one.
3. `[[23 + 5][23 + 5]]`, then the outer one.
4. The last substitution will not do anything and the loop will exit.

Using the `g` flag at the end of the substitution expression will cause the first two steps above to be carried out in the same substitution as they are non-overlapping.

---

With an equivalent basic regular expressions (the above uses an extended regular expression for readability):

```
sed -e ':loop' -e 's/(\([^()][^()]*\))/[\1]/; tloop' <file
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the crystal clear explanation!